# Django convert Model to sql code

Tags: sql, django, model

My plan is to be able to dynamically generate SQL tables. Since I know django can create SQL tables using models, they must have a function for this. The problem is I can not find this function in the Django folder, or maybe I simply don't recognize it.
thnx

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/schema-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the specific pieces of code, have a look at [`django.db.backends.base.creation`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/creation.py) to see how the sql is generated, of course there need to be individual implementations for different database types, so for example also see [`django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/creation.py)!

Comment: Can you fix the broken link?

Answer (score 2):

It's called `django-admin.py`

Start here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Specifically, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sql

Comment: I'm looking for the specific function actually. This way I can implement it in my python script.

Comment: @Benjamin: You can import and execute that.  Further, you can read the source to see how they do it.  It's quite clear from reading the source.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you mean, but you can get the SQL for all the tables in an app by running this command:
`python manage.py sqlall your_app`

Comment: It's `sqlmigrate` now